# Laravel 5 / Vue JS : Route for Get request route return Object or Array depending Eloquent query

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, object, vuejs2

I'm new on Laravel 5.4 and Vue js 2 and I'm confronted whith this issue that I can solve.

I've got a controller with 2 methods (and route associated) :

```
public function index()
{
    //
    return BookingPayment::all();
}

public function index_booking($id_booking)
{
    return BookingPayment::all()
        ->where('id_booking', '=', $id_booking)
        ->toArray(); // <<-- no effects !?
}
```

Method `index` return all rows in my table, `index_booking` do a filter id_booking fields.

In php my PHP page I have a javascript which do a request on those two routes.
My problem is when i use `index_booking`, request returns me an Object. I expect an array as I will be able to easyly use array function to manipulate the results.

Here is my javascript :

```
var vm = new Vue({

el: '#bookingpay',

data: function () {
    return {
        booking_id: 15,
        payments: [],
        input: [{id: 0, id_booking: 0, new_amount: 99}]
    }
},

mounted: function () {
    this.fetchPayment();
},

methods: {

    fetchPayment: function () {
        this.$http.get('/api/bookingpayments_bybooking/' + this.booking_id).then(function (response) {
            this.payments = response.data;
        })
    },

    delPayment: function (id, index) {
        this.$http.delete('/api/bookingpayments/' + id).then(function () {
            this.payments.splice(index, 1); // doesn't work on Ojbect
        })
    },

    addPayment: function () {
        this.$http.post('/api/bookingpayments', this.input).then(function () {
            this.payments.push(this.input);
        })
    },

}

});
```

This is the kind of format that i expect as a http query response. It's what i have when I use index :
`[
  {
    "id": 79,
    "id_booking": 3,
    "amount": "10.00"
  },
  {
    "id": 80,
    "id_booking": 3,
    "amount": "10.00"
  },`
    ....

This is what I have when I use `index_booking` :

`{
  "28": {
    "id": 29,
    "id_booking": 15,
    "amount": "45.00"
  },
  "29": {
    "id": 30,
    "id_booking": 15,
    "amount": "48.00"
  }
}`

I'm stuck ! Any help will be really appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Is `BookingPayment` an Eloquent model?

Comment: yes it is ! Ian solved my problem. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `index_booking` is wrong. The correct way is:

```
public function index_booking($id_booking)
{
    // This will return a Collection that will be translated to an array/json when you hit the endpoint via ajax. There is no need for toArray(), though...
    return BookingPayment::where('id_booking', '=', $id_booking)->get();
}
```

Comment: That's solve my problem. thanks for your help mate !